# Sewer Access Pipe

Tags: sewer

So I demolished my sewer access cap/pipe with the lawn mower. I was wondering exactly how to fix it. One choice would obviously be to dig down to it and replace the pipe and cap. I also thought about cutting it flush and just getting a new cap. Another option I thought of was to get a pipe that is slightly a smaller diameter and stick it most of the way down and cap it.

Which option is better, or what should I do?

[image]

Comment: Cut it lower and put on a new cap.   If your worried about it getting covered up take two measurements to static points that form something resembling a triangle (i.e. a corner of the foundation and a fence post--any two angled points-- best way to do it is with two measuring tapes)

Comment: @Tyson I put a new cap on it and it almost covered all of the damage. There's maybe an inch crack that is still exposed but it's small enough to where it won't get clogged. I may glue the cracked part or cut the pipe a bit.  Thanks for the info!